# Is this transformation of a Markov process again Markovian?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a stationary Markov process valued in $\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Is the process $(Y_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ defined by
$$
Y_t={\bf 1}{(X_t<c)}
$$
again a Markov process (valued in $\{0,1\}$)? Here ${\bf 1}$ denotes the characteristic function, i.e. it is $1$ if $X_t<c$ and $0$ otherwise. The main example I'm interested in is $X_t$ being an $\rm{AR}(1)$ process, so I would also appreciate answers for this special case.

I tried, for example, to show that
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y_t=0 \ \mid \ Y_{t-1}=0,\dots, Y_0=0)=\mathbb{P}(Y_t=0 \ \mid \ Y_{t-1}=0)
$$
using the Markov property of $Y_t$ and marginalization, but I was not able to show the equality of the resulting integrals, which lead me to believe that $Y_t$ is actually not a Markov process.

I would really appreciate any help or a reference for these type of results/proofs/counterexamples.

Comment: Considering some non-injective function of a Markov process is a classical way to destroy Markovianity hence, in general, $Y$ is not Markov. A case where one  can show relatively easily that indeed $Y$ is not Markov is when $X$ is the simple random walk on $\mathbb Z$, then $$P(Y_t=0\mid Y_{t-1}=\cdots=Y_{t-n}=0,Y_{t-n-1}=1)=P(T>n+1\mid T>n),$$ where $T$ is the first hitting time of $1$ by $X$ starting from $0$. Since $T$ is not geometric, the RHS very much depends on $n$ hence $Y$ is not Markov (and not Markov of some higher order either).

Comment: @Did Thank you very much for the good example! Do you also happen to know an example of a stationary process where this fails (e.g. a stationary $\rm{AR}(1)$ with normal white noise) or do you think it could generally be true in this setting?

Comment: Of course the property also fails for AR processes, for basically the same reason: the distribution of $Y_t$, $n$ steps after entering the zone $(c,+\infty)$, depends on $n$.

Comment: @Did Thanks again! I see the point, however its not fully clear to me how to proof/compute this formally. Sorry for being slow here. I would appeciate any further comments.